# Pandas import two csv files and plot specific data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

[link 1](https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/tableservices/jsf/pages/productview.xhtml?src=bkmk)
[link 2](http://www.thearda.com/denoms/D_836_d.asp) *I copied table and created csv file

I need to plot total population from file 1 and Adherents total for New Jersey as a line or bar graph to compare.

I've tried append to combine both cvs's but comes out weird

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

clifton_data = pd.read_csv('cliftondata2010census.csv')

religion = pd.read_csv('2010_ Top Five States by Adherence Rate - Sheet1.csv')

all_data = clifton_data.append(religion)
all_data.plot()
all_data.plot(kind='line',x='1',y='2') # scatter plot
all_data.plot(kind='density')
```

I need to plot total population from file 1 and compare to Adherents total for New Jersey as a line or bar graph.

Comment: The data is not available on the website. Can you share a sample?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick guide to get you stared. I hope it helps.

From link 2, you see

```
Massachusetts   641     2,940,199   449.05
Rhode Island    159     466,598     443.30
New Jersey      729     3,235,290   367.99
Connecticut     399     1,252,936   350.56
New York        1,630   6,286,916   324.43
```

copy the texts above, paste and save the data to `congregation.txt`.

Link 1 is broken. However, assuming the population data are as follows,

```
Massachusetts   3,141,270
Rhode Island    530,698
New Jersey      4,335,399
Connecticut     2,134,935
New York        10,366,556
```

similarly, copy the texts above, paste and save the data to `population.txt`.

Then, you can run something like this

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

con = pd.read_csv('congregation.txt', sep=r'[ \t]{2,}',header=None, index_col=False,engine='python')
pop = pd.read_csv('population.txt', sep=r'[ \t]{2,}',header=None, index_col=False,engine='python')

#note concat and not append
#con[0] is state, con[2] is congregation, pop[1] is population
#print(con.head()) and print(pop.head()) to visualize if you are still confused
df = pd.concat([con[[0,2]],pop[1]],axis=1)

df.columns = ['State', 'Congregation', 'Population']

#need to do some cleaning here to convert numbers with comma to an integer
df['Congregation'] = df['Congregation'].apply(lambda t: t.replace(',','')).astype(int)
df['Population'] = df['Population'].apply(lambda t: t.replace(',','')).astype(int)

df.set_index('State',inplace=True)

print(df.head())
#at this stage your df looks like this
#               Congregation  Population
#State                                  
#Massachusetts       2940199     3141270
#Rhode Island         466598      530698
#New Jersey          3235290     4335399
#Connecticut         1252936     2134935
#New York            6286916    10366556
```

Output

Note: I am retaining other states here for the sake of demonstration, otherwise if it is only *New Jersey*, the bar plot will look empty.

```
ax = df.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Edit: I meant 'Adherent' not 'Congregation'. I made a mistake there.

Comment: this is the link for the 2010 population of clifton NJ https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/tableservices/jsf/pages/productview.xhtml?src=CF..... I need to compare clifton Nj population in 2010 vs NJ Adherents total

Comment: I also get error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Adherents'

Comment: @WhitneyHughes The new link is not working for me- An error has occurred in American FactFinder.